# GridView in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm a .Net Developer and new to Java environment. I'm currently I'm using Netbeans 7.1. In Windows Forms there are `DatagridView`, `ListBox`, and `ListView`. What are the equivalent controls present in Swing, specifically `DatagridView`? How can I bind those grid in `ResultSet`?

Suggested links for tutorial are very much appreciated.

Comment: Please describe the desired features of the components mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) describes the component list available in Swing. For GridView you can choose JTable.

---

Also if you are willing to use [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/), then there you will find, JXTable, JXTreeTable.

Comment: You are welcome. I have edited my answer with more information. Also if this answer is helpful then please up-vote it.